# php with xml inside cdata

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

I have an xml document with another xml document inside a cdata. I need to read the inner xml, but that xml has some invalid xml characters like "&", that is why it is inclosed in a cdata.

An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <outResponse>
         <outReturn>
            <resultData><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DATA><group ID="P12"><FLD NAME="companycode">E173</FLD><FLD NAME="data_link">https://local-services/getkey?&api_key=9999</FLD></group></DATA>]]></resultData>
         </outReturn>
      </outResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this example, I need to get the value from companycode fld tag.

I already tried this using

```
$myXML = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse->xpath('//resultData')[0], 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

But it doesnt work. All the resultData content is encoding (all the "< >" and & characters even those from the nodes) but then I can't load the resulting xml, in order to get the pretended value.

I also tried to use DOMDocument() without success. The problem is always the same: load the xml inside cdata so that I can then get the target element value.

The only way I was able to achieve this so far was to work with the cdata content as string, and make a find repalce of the "&" value for "&". Then I can load the xml and get the value, but this doesnt seems a good practice, because I may get an xml with other characters that need to be encoding.

So what I need is a way to load that xml without ignoring the cdata, or in order words, without ignoring the need to replace some charcacters automatically.

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

thank you

Comment: You can easily split this into two parts: first, to get the string from that node, just do `$brokenXML = (string)$xmlResponse->xpath('//resultData')[0];` Then ignore where it came from, and you have a classic "I need to parse invalid XML" question.

Comment: thank you for the edit Nick. IMSop, thank you for the answer, but the xml is only invalid if cdata is removed. That is what I want to avoid. My goal is to understand if php has a way of dealing with cdata as expected.

Comment: The invalid XML is the string `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DATA><group ID="P12"><FLD NAME="companycode">E173</FLD><FLD NAME="data_link">https://local-services/getkey?&api_key=9999</FLD></group></DATA>` Wherever you put that string, it will not become valid XML until you fix the unescaped `&`

Comment: To give a simplified example, `<foo><![CDATA[&&hello&&]]></foo>` is valid XML, which contains the string `&&hello&&`. However, nothing you do will make `&&hello&&` on its own valid XML, so you would not be able to use an XML parser to extract the string `hello` from it.